# Inserting Missing dates in rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

I have this data frame where weather data is available.

**Problem** - My problem is when I try to add missing dates with the code below:-

```
dt = pd.date_range("01-01-2021","01-11-2021")

idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(dt)

new_df9 = df_missing_values.reindex(idx)
```

After adding the dates - 2021-02-01, all my data in temperature, windspeed and event columns transformed to NaN values. As you can see in the image below:-

[image]

Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: Hey Gabriel, Yes I have checked, index is in DateTime index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, your data is identified as monthly data.
For example, the second row is the first of April of 2021, that is why when you reindex until the 11th of January the rest of the data is gone.

You might need to correct the index first to `2021-01-04` instead of `2021-04-01` if the data corresponds to the 4th of January instead of the 1st of April

Comment: hey Gabriel, Can you please guide me to it?

Comment: Sure, you can transform it to string and back again to datetime in another format, like this

`df_missing_data.index = pd.to_datetime(df_missing_data.index.astype(str), format='%Y-%d-%m')`.

The `df_missing_data.index.astype(str)` transform your index back to string, then the `pd.to_datetime(<string-index>, format='%Y-%d-%m')` transform the string version of the index back to datetime telling it to use the second value as the day `%d` and the last one as the month `%m`

Comment: Please change df_missing_data to df_missing_values. Thanks, Gabriel, it helped a lot, I fixed this issue.